# Excel worksheet names to change based on an existing cell in an existing worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of values in my first worksheet at M6 to M12.
I want the first worksheet name to be the content of reference M6.
I want the second worksheet name to be the content of reference M7 and so on.
If I select Rename and type =M6 on the first worksheet, I get the desired value.
However, when I go to my next sheet and select Rename and try to reference the first sheet and the cell, this does not work.
Any guidance would be appreciated.

In addition, the content of the worksheet name is already being successfully displayed in a cell on the specific sheet that I wish to name.
That is to say, on sheet 2, cell B3 contains the reference from sheet 1 cell M7. This is the value I want to get into my worksheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Richard, I cannot simulate the process you described in my Excel.  Besides it will likely to cause circular/invalid references.
Anyway, assuming your sheet#2 is the next sheet after your sheet#1 which stores the references,
below macro should work for you without causing any circular references.

```
Sub Macro1()
If MsgBox("Is this your main sheet", vbYesNoCancel, "Is this your main sheet") = vbYes Then
    ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("m6").Value
    newSheet1Name = ActiveSheet.Range("m6").Value
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets(CStr(newSheet1Name)).Range("m7").Value
    ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
    MsgBox "Sheet names updated !"
Else:
    MsgBox "Cancelled !"
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```